# How to set mail and password in pgadmin 4 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pgadmin, ubuntu-20.04

I already had pgadmin installed before ubuntu was updated to 20.04. Once it was updated, I realized that pgadmin had disappeared (my databases in postgresql are still there intact) and I followed the instructions below to install pgadmin4:

[How to Install PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4 in Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-and-pgadmin-in-ubuntu/)

At some point it was supposed to ask me to configure an account with my email and password, but it never did, now I am able to get to the home screen but I cannot login because I did not configure an email and password.
Any help is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

I removed

```
/var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
```

file. It was first start pgadmin4 for me so there were nothing important

And then I run

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

again and it ask for email\password

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/pgadmin/pgadmin.db` for removing the file and it will work just fine. Thank you maria for the answer.

Comment: After doing all the steps above, instead of refreshing the browser, I closed it and opened and new tab with the same address:  http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4. Thanks Maria.